# How to select from a list of columns? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of columns attained through a SQL query.

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
    SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
    c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
ORDER BY table_name
```

Now for each column, I want to query some information about the column and put them together in a table.

Here is the query I would run for a single column, for example.

```
Select Substring(col1, 1, 1) letter, Count(Substring(col1, 1, 1)) cnt
From tbl
Group By Substring(col1, 1, 1)
```

What this subquery does is that it attains the count of the first character of records in a column. So for example, there may be 6 records in col1 that start with the letter 'a', 15 records in col1 that start with the letter 'b', etc.

How do I combine these two queries together into one table so I get something like...

```
Table_Name, Column_Name, letter, cnt

    tbl, col1, a, 6

    tbl, col1, b, 15

    tbl, col2, a, 5

    ...
```

Comment: What a totally bizarre requirement. Can you explain how this could have any real world use? And what is the column cnt really trying to show? The length of the data? What about columns that are not character data?

Comment: @SeanLange I am profiling the columns of a database. The first character of the record of a column happens to contain information about the data format contained in the record. So what this query does is it tallies the count of the data format for each relevant column in the database. For example, in my sample table, now I know that col1 has 6 records with data format a and 15 records with data format b. col2 has 5 records in data format a.

Comment: Gotcha. Of course this is needed because your data is not properly normalized. You are shoving two pieces of information into a single column which violates 1NF and causes things like this to be extra challenging. To achieve what you need here you will need to extend the work below for Yogesh to include dynamic sql to get all the information you need. This would be SO much simpler if you had properly normalized structures. This is not going to be easy.

Comment: Maybe if you can share a table and some sample data that represent the problem (and include the desired output) we can help. As it sits I kind of get what you are after but the implementation is a little fuzzy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this useful?

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(Max)

SELECT @query=COALESCE(@query + ' union all ', '') + CAST('SELECT ''' +TABLE_SCHEMA+''' As [Schema],'''+TABLE_NAME+''' As TableName,'''+COLUMN_NAME+''' As ColumnName, Substring(['+COLUMN_NAME+'],1,1) letter,COUNT(Substring(['+COLUMN_NAME+'],1,1)) cnt
FROM '+TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME+
' Group by Substring(['+COLUMN_NAME+'],1,1)' AS VARCHAR(MAX))
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE DATA_TYPE IN('varchar','char','nvarchar') 

--SELECT @query
Exec(@query)
```

Comment: That worked! You are absolutely amazing. I am so grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You want this :

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
       c.name AS column_name, t1.letter, count(*) as cnt
FROM sys.tables AS t INNER JOIN 
     sys.columns c 
     ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID 
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (Substring(c.name, 1, 1)) ) t1(letter)
GROUP BY t.name, c.name, t1.letter;
```

Comment: So close! That subquery attains the first letter of each column name (ex. col1 -> c). But what I need is the first letter of the contents of the column (ex. col1 -> a, b if the column contains apple, bakery, etc.)